# Delimiter Character in Attribute Column

Tags: python, csv

I have a file that is Tab Delimited.  One of those columns is text-input, that often times contains tabs.

So it's something like

```
ID            Phone              Text                 Time
######        ########         blahblah \t\t i know   YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

So when I read file in (python) and separate by tabs it clearly messes things up.  Is there a way to target specific tabs?  Say "delimit on the first, second, and last" within a line?  Is there an efficient way to remove the tabs within the text field? I can replace them with anything, a -, a space, doesn't matter they're non-important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're reading in the lines, and you know that there won't be tabs in the other fields you could do something like this:

```
f = open('your_file.txt','r')

id,phone,text,tm = [],[],[],[]
for i,line in enumerate(f):
    if i == 0:
        continue
    fields = line.strip().split('\t')
    id.append(fields[0])
    phone.append(fields[1])
    text.append('\t'.join(fields[2:-1]))
    tm.append(fields[-1])

f.close()
```

This will preserve the tabs in your text field as well.  You can join them with a different character if you want to get rid of them.

Comment: This seems to work on several of the test examples I saw. Feels silly, because this should have been the obvious solution from the get go. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad that it was able to work for you :)